# Dataflow: Consuming runtime parameters in template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Trying to create a template for dataflow job.

Is there any way to generate a template with runtime parameters?

Till now, whatever parameters were used at the time of creation of template, but when I tried passing different values for the variables, it is not picking the runtime values.

If any additional details are needed, will provide the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use value providers in your pipeline options to have runtime arguments in a pipeline.

But I'm afraid that this is too limited to where you can use these parameters (Mostly in DoFn).

This behaviour is expected from dataflow template as it is *representation of a pipeline* rather than the code itself.

Please bear in mind that **you cannot create dataflow template with dynamic processing steps based on the value passed**.

The steps are hard-coded into the template and cannot be changed unless the code to generate the template is executed again.

Answer (score 1):

A parameter needs to be wrapped inside of a ValueProvider object in order for the template pipeline to access the runtime value of that parameter. All of the example templates provided [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates) demonstrate how ValueProvider can be used to parameterize a template pipeline.

Take a look at the [WordCount pipeline](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/WordCount.java) as an example.

As you can see, the pipeline uses a ValueProvider (instead of a simple String) to read the path of the file on which a WordCount needs to be executed:

```
@Description("Path of the file to read from")
ValueProvider<String> getInputFile();
void setInputFile(ValueProvider<String> value);
```

Since the value of the inputFile is unknown until runtime (when the template is actually executed with valid inputs), the transform using the ValueProvider will defer reading the value of the parameter until runtime (for e.g. inside a DoFn).

The native TextIO.Read Beam transform [provides support](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Read.html) for reading from a ValueProvider in addition to reading from String.

Comment: is there an example in python for reference.